# Is it possible to make the mean of the list of numbers generated from the normal distribution become exactly zero?

Tags: python, floating-accuracy

So, even in the absence of errors due to the finite machine precision it would be mathematically incorrect to think of a scenario where *finite* number of points sampled from a Gaussian distribution give exactly zero mean always. One would truly need an infinite number of points for this to be exactly true.

Nonetheless, I am manually (in an ad hoc manner) trying to center the distribution so that the mean is at zero. For that I first generate a gaussian distribution, find it's mean and then shift each point with that mean. By doing this I take the mean very close to zero but then I encounter a small value close to the machine precision (of the order `10**(-17)`) and I do not know how to make it exactly zero.

Here is the code I used:

```
import numpy as np
n=10000
X=np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,n))[0,:]
Xm=np.mean(X)
print("Xm = ", Xm)
Y=np.random.normal(0,1,size=(2,n))[1,:]
Ym=np.mean(Ym)
print("Ym = ", Y)

for i in range(len(X)):
  X[i]=X[i]-Xm
  Y[i]=Y[i]-Ym

new_X=np.mean(X)
new_Y=np.mean(Y)
print(new_X)
print(new_Y)

Output:
Zreli =  0.002713682499601005
Preli =  -0.0011499576497770079
-3.552713678800501e-18
2.2026824808563105e-17
```

Comment: If you're at machine precision levels, can't you modify a single value in your sample to achieve your desired mean?

Comment: In general, it is impossible to make the mean zero by adding a displacement to all the samples. Suppose the randomly obtained samples are +1, −1, and +3•2^−100. Their mean is 2^−100, so you would have to add −2^−100 to each sample to translate them to have a mean of zero. But you cannot form +1−2^−100 because it is not representable in the floating-point format.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make the mean zero with non-uniform adjustments, such as changing the +3•2^−100 sample to zero and leaving the others at +1 and −1. But then you have to decide what adjustments are acceptable. This one changed a sample by 100% of the sample’s magnitude. Is that acceptable? Further, even if the sum of all the samples is zero (and hence their mean is zero), that does not mean that adding them in some order with floating-point arithmetic will produce a sum of zero, because the additions will have their own rounding errors. Do you need the calculated sum to be zero?

Comment: @Eric Postpischil. The non-uniform additions are unacceptable as that will change the distribution from gaussian. Also, it looks like from " even if the sum of all the samples is zero (and hence their mean is zero), that does not mean that adding them in some order with floating-point arithmetic will produce a sum of zero, because the additions will have their own rounding errors."  that the task is futile and I would have to live that small mean value. The reason I was trying to do this was to see how much this contributed to the noise in my signal but I guess it's contributions are less

Answer (score 0):

I am not good with code but mathematically you could have a while loop that checks for the sum of the numbers you have to not be 0. If it isn't 0 you would add 1 to the lowest unit you allow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).